# Mysql query default value '' not equal java ""

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, mybatis

I'm using Mybatis query database

mysql table structure

[image]

parent_id default is `''`

insert value is

[image]

Mybatis get value seem error? , `parent_id` should be `""` instead null value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your value in DB is empty string and in your Java object is int/Integer, MyBatis cannot cast the column. To solve this, you can either:

- Modify your database to make parent_id default null
- Modify your select query and change column parent_id to `IF(parent_id = '', null, parent_id) as parent_id`